# how to get info from a service for another service

Tags: android, android-service

A design question. Lets say I have a service A that receives location updates. And lets say that I have another IntentService B that receives push notifications. Now in this service B, if I get a certain push notification, I want to retrieve the last received location in order to do some calculations on it.

How would I go about it? I thought about saving the location in service A in shared pref and retrieve it in B. OR store the location in a static variable that I can retrieve in Service B. But this seems bad design to me.

Any recommendation how I can achieve what I want properly?

Thank you

Comment: why not wait until B receive push notif, then service A get the last location and do the calculate?

Comment: You can bind the two services in order to access other service's private data.

Comment: Use a messenger service.When you receive the trigger push notification in B,you send request to A which will fetch you the most recent/more accurate location.Rather you could convert the one of the services to a messenger service.

Comment: yes this is bad design with static variables...you know static variables lost all stored data if app get crashed but sharedPreference stores data even after app crashing. So go with sharedPreference.

Comment: @IndexOutOfBounds , thats a good idea. I didn't know that you can have services bound to each other. I guess I can have B bind to A even though  A is started a while ago .right? Can Intentservice bind to a service?

Comment: @Droidekas I like your idea but how can I send a request from B to A? That's really my problem.

Comment: Do you want a wordy suggestion  or in code?

Comment: Are these in different apps?If not then a bound service would work better.

Comment: This is the same app. Whichever answer you prefer. Always code is prefered but I dont mind wordy answer